# Recognize contact only on bottom of circle. Cocos2d with Box2d

Tags: iphone, ipad, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I am making a platform game for iPad and iPhone using Cocos2d and Box2d.
I am adding some special functionality on the jumping, and I need to know when my character should be allowed to jump.

Currently I am using a ContactManager to check for collisions between the player (a circle) and other objects. This way I can tell my character that he is only allowed to jump when he is in contact with another object.

The problem is that I do not want him to be able to jump off walls...
I want to know whether my character is in contact with another object on the bottom of my circle! He should only be able to jump when he's got his feet on the ground. Not his face...

How should I approach this?

Comment: to check if contact point is at the bottom of the character ?

Comment: Yes. I want to find out if the characters is landing "on his feet"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can attach a small sensor fixture to the bottom of your character and check for collisions with it.
http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/jumpability

Answer (score 1):

You can get the list of contact points like this:

```
b2Manifold* manifold = contact->GetManifold();
for (int i = 0; i < manifold.pointCount; i++)
{
   b2ManifoldPoint point = manifold.points[i];
   // rest see text …
}
```

Now in theory all you need to do is to check if there's at least one point in the bottom-most area of your player circle. That means if a contact point's x position is within the range of about plus/minus half the circle radius, and the y position is smaller than the circle body's y position, then you have a collision of the circle somewhere at the ground level.

Comment: I am sorry. I am not getting this to work.
How do I continue to get the correct positions, widths and heights of my b2bodies?

Comment: b2Body* bodyA = contact->GetFixtureA()->GetBody();
Same for bodyB. You can then work with the body's properties like position etc.

Comment: See the Box2D API Reference: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest/Box2D/html/classb2_contact.html